# call a function with setInterval multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I have two include files (php) with input fields that needs to be updated by setInterval. both of them will show the same input value.

My problem is that on some cases i will only include one file and sometimes i'll include both of them.
I don't want to have an ajax call on both of the includes file because i will get the same data twice. i also don't want to have one call on one file because i don't know which file will ALWAYS load.

I tried to have a different file (lets say core.js) that will have the ajax function with his own setInterval and i will call this function from each include file. then (i was thinking it will work), when one file calls to the ajax, it will kill the interval and start again. BUT i want the function to keep the on success function from the first call.

Does that make sense?
if not, i'll be happy to hear about other options.

[image]

Comment: why don't you include the js in the parent page?

Comment: because i want this on all of my pages.

Comment: so if the js is on parent page then it will be executed for all other included pages as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your function in a separate file to prevent code duplication. In that same file declare a variable on the global scope and then in each of your include files do something like the following (assuming your global var is timer)

```
// Start timer
if ( typeof timer === 'undefined' ) {
    timer = setInterval( funcName, 1000 );
}
```

That will check to see if the timer has already been declared, and set the interval if it hasn't.